# AngularProxy to DotNetCore not working asking for CORS

Tags: angular, .net-core, http-proxy

I'm trying to setup my angular-cli app to use a proxy so i doesnt need CORS on my web server.

my DotNetCore server run on port 49274.
my angular-cli app run on 4200

I'm pretty sure the proxy is there to remove the CORS errors...

but i'm still getting CORS errors...

```
beer/list:1 Failed to load http://localhost:49274/api/beer: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

core.js:1601 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
```

Here are the list of config i've tried...

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49274",
    "secure": false
  }
}

{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49274",
    "secure": false
  }
}

{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49274",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}

{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49274",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}

{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49274",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : "http://localhost:49274/api"}
  }
}


{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49274",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : "http://localhost:49274/api"}
  }
}

{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49274",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}

{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49274",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

damn... after looking closely to my code... i've found the bug were in my environment.ts .... so much effort for a simple thing!

i had

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:49274/api/'
```

};

and apiUrl should have been '/api/' ...! i finally got it working :)